# how can I automatically get the data from SAP BO to my BI tools such as Spotfire or Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, spotfire, business-objects

We are using SAP BO to store our data. But we are using different BI tools to creat creative dashboards. My problem is I am not able to connect my BI tools with SAP BO. So I want to get data from SAP BO to the my dashboards automatically not by doing manual processes.

how can I get data from automatically from SAP BO to my BI tools such as Spotfire or Power BI? Is there any way?
Thanks for helps!

Comment: Can you check this article please - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-connectivity-to-sap-businessobjects-bi-now-generally-available/#:~:text=Power%20BI%20Connectivity%20to%20SAP%20BusinessObjects%20BI%20Now%20Generally%20Available,-The%20Power%20BI&text=Seamless%20access%20to%20trusted%20enterprise,BW%20and%20SAP%20Business%20Suite.

Comment: Spotfire has connectors to SAP BW , but not to BO .